# how to do i get user id from JWT token?

Tags: node.js, api, express, jwt, token

I need to get the id of the logged in user in my JWT token, in `console.log(decoded)` I can get all decoded info but I only need id, any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
logIn: (req, res) =>{
    const body = req.body;
    GetUserByUserEmail(body.email, (err, results)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        if(!results) {
            return res.json({
                success: 0,
                data: 'Invalid email or password'
            });
        }
        const result = compareSync(body.seller_password, results.seller_password);
        if(result){
            results.seller_password = undefined;
            const jsontoken = sign({result: results},
                 process.env.JWT_secret_key, {expiresIn: '24h'});
                 res.json({
                     success: 1,
                     data: 'logIn successfully',
                     token: jsontoken
                     });
                   const decoded = decode(jsontoken)
                   console.log(decoded)
        } else {
            return res.json ({
                success: 0,
                data: 'Invalid email or password'
            });
        }
    })
```

Comment: nope, that's not my case, i guess i need to know how i can get user id from from the the decoded token, because i have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Did you read the complete  answer of the linked question? It's simply decoded.id or whatever the fieldname is.

Comment: i tried the decoded.id too but in console log it returns undefined, don't know why!

Comment: What's the output of console.log(decoded)?

Comment: {
  result: {
    seller_id: 165,
    seller_name: 'avdd',
    last_name: 'varr',
    email: 'ehsan.samadi1000@gmail.com'
  },
  iat: 1598720545,
  exp: 1598806945
}
POST /api/users/logIn 200 213.743 ms - 319

Comment: returns the complete array

Comment: console.log(decoded.result.seller_id), this finally worked, thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: great! That's why I said in the linked answer, that you can inspect your token on jwt.io and see what's actually inside. Of course you can access the id only if you have an id and if you have a seller_id in a nested result object then it's decoded.result.seller_id as you already figured out. The linked answer of course can't answer every individual case, but from reading it, you should understand the principle.

Comment: I updated the linked answer to reflect the more complex case with a nested object as well. Can you approve the suggested duplicate?

Comment: bravo, that's great.  happy that you updated that answer too.